# starting flume agent shows an error with respect to the jdk path that it is a directory and cannot execute

Tags: java, hadoop

I am facing an error in `flume` installation.
I am unable to start `flume agent` due to the `jdk` path shown as a directory and cannot execute.
Please help me to get rid of this problem in order to get the `JSON` data in my `hdfs`

```
hadoop1@ubuntu:~/Downloads/apache-flume-1.6.0-bin$ bin/flume-ng agent -conf ./conf/ -f conf/flume.conf -Dflume.root.logger=DEBUG,console -n TwitterAgent
Warning: No configuration directory set! Use --conf <dir> to override.
Info: Including Hadoop libraries found via (/home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/bin/hadoop) for HDFS access
Info: Excluding /home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-api-1.7.10.jar from classpath
Info: Excluding /home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.10.jar from classpath
Info: Including Hive libraries found via () for Hive access
+ exec /usr/lib/java/jdk1.8.0_131 bin/java -Xmx20m -Dflume.root.logger=DEBUG,console -cp '/home/hadoop1/Downloads/apache-flume-1.6.0-bin/lib/*:/home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/etc/hadoop:/home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/activation-1.1.jar:/home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/apacheds-i18n-2.0.0-M15.jar:/home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/apacheds-kerberos-codec-2.0.0-M15.jar:/home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/api-asn1-api-1.0.0-M20.jar:/home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/api-util-1.0.0-M20.jar:/home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/asm-3.2.jar:/home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/avro-1.7.4.jar:/home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar:/home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-beanutils-core-1.8.0.jar:/home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-cli-1.2.jar:/home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-codec-1.4.jar:/home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar:/home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-compress-1.4.1.jar:/home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-configuration-1.6.jar:/home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-digester-1.8.jar:/home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-httpclient-3.1.jar:/home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-io-2.4.jar:/home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-lang-2.6.jar:/home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-logging-1.1.3.jar:/home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-math3-3.1.1.jar:/home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-net-3.1.jar:/home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/curator-client-2.7.1.jar:/home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/curator-framework-2.7.1.jar:/home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/curator-recipes-2.7.1.jar:/home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/gson-2.2.4.jar:/home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/guava-11.0.2.jar:/home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/hadoop-annotations-2.7.1.jar:/home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/hadoop-auth-2.7.1.jar:/home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar:/home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/htrace-core-3.1.0-incubating.jar:/home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/httpclient-4.2.5.jar:/home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/httpcore-4.2.5.jar:/home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar:/home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jackson-jaxrs-1.9.13.jar:/home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar:/home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jackson-xc-1.9.13.jar:/home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/java-xmlbuilder-0.4.jar:/home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jaxb-api-2.2.2.jar:/home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jaxb-impl-2.2.3-1.jar:/home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jersey-core-1.9.jar:/home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jersey-json-1.9.jar:/home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jersey-server-1.9.jar:/home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jets3t-0.9.0.jar:/home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jettison-1.1.jar:/home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jetty-6.1.26.jar:/home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jetty-util-6.1.26.jar:/home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jsch-0.1.42.jar:/home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jsp-api-2.1.jar:/home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jsr305-3.0.0.jar:/home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/junit-4.11.jar:/home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar:/home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/mockito-all-1.8.5.jar:/home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/netty-3.6.2.Final.jar:/home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/paranamer-2.3.jar:/home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar:/home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/servlet-api-2.5.jar:/home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/snappy-java-1.0.4.1.jar:/home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/stax-api-1.0-2.jar:/home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/xmlenc-0.52.jar:/home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/xz-1.0.jar:/home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/zookeeper-3.4.6.jar:/home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/hadoop-common-2.7.1.jar:/home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/hadoop-common-2.7.1-tests.jar:/home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/hadoop-nfs-2.7.1.jar:/home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/jdiff:/home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib:/home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/sources:/home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/templates:/home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs:/home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/asm-3.2.jar:/home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/commons-cli-1.2.jar:/home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/commons-codec-1.4.jar:/home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/commons-daemon-1.0.13.jar:/home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/commons-io-2.4.jar:/home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/commons-lang-2.6.jar:/home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/commons-logging-1.1.3.jar:/home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/guava-11.0.2.jar:/home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/htrace-core-3.1.0-incubating.jar:/home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar:/home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar:/home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/jersey-core-1.9.jar:/home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/jersey-server-1.9.jar:/home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/jetty-6.1.26.jar:/home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/jetty-util-6.1.26.jar:/home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/jsr305-3.0.0.jar:/home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/leveldbjni-all-1.8.jar:/home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar:/home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/netty-3.6.2.Final.jar:/home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/netty-all-4.0.23.Final.jar:/home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar:/home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/servlet-api-2.5.jar:/home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/xercesImpl-2.9.1.jar:/home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/xml-apis-1.3.04.jar:/home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/xmlenc-0.52.jar:/home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/hadoop-hdfs-2.7.1.jar:/home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/hadoop-hdfs-2.7.1-tests.jar:/home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/hadoop-hdfs-nfs-2.7.1.jar:/home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/jdiff:/home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib:/home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/sources:/home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/templates:/home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/webapps:/home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/activation-1.1.jar:/home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/aopalliance-1.0.jar:/home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/asm-3.2.jar:/home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/commons-cli-1.2.jar:/home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/commons-codec-1.4.jar:/home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar:/home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/commons-compress-1.4.1.jar:/home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/commons-io-2.4.jar:/home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/commons-lang-2.6.jar:/home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/commons-logging-1.1.3.jar:/home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/guava-11.0.2.jar:/home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/guice-3.0.jar:/home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/guice-servlet-3.0.jar:/home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar:/home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jackson-jaxrs-1.9.13.jar:/home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar:/home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jackson-xc-1.9.13.jar:/home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/javax.inject-1.jar:/home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jaxb-api-2.2.2.jar:/home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jaxb-impl-2.2.3-1.jar:/home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jersey-client-1.9.jar:/home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jersey-core-1.9.jar:/home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jersey-guice-1.9.jar:/home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jersey-json-1.9.jar:/home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jersey-server-1.9.jar:/home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jettison-1.1.jar:/home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jetty-6.1.26.jar:/home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jetty-util-6.1.26.jar:/home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jsr305-3.0.0.jar:/home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/leveldbjni-all-1.8.jar:/home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar:/home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/netty-3.6.2.Final.jar:/home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar:/home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/servlet-api-2.5.jar:/home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/stax-api-1.0-2.jar:/home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/xz-1.0.jar:/home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/zookeeper-3.4.6.jar:/home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/zookeeper-3.4.6-tests.jar:/home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-api-2.7.1.jar:/home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-applications-distributedshell-2.7.1.jar:/home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-applications-unmanaged-am-launcher-2.7.1.jar:/home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-client-2.7.1.jar:/home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-common-2.7.1.jar:/home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-registry-2.7.1.jar:/home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-server-applicationhistoryservice-2.7.1.jar:/home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-server-common-2.7.1.jar:/home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-server-nodemanager-2.7.1.jar:/home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-server-resourcemanager-2.7.1.jar:/home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-server-sharedcachemanager-2.7.1.jar:/home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-server-tests-2.7.1.jar:/home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-server-web-proxy-2.7.1.jar:/home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib:/home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/sources:/home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/test:/home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/aopalliance-1.0.jar:/home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/asm-3.2.jar:/home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/avro-1.7.4.jar:/home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/commons-compress-1.4.1.jar:/home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/commons-io-2.4.jar:/home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/guice-3.0.jar:/home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/guice-servlet-3.0.jar:/home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/hadoop-annotations-2.7.1.jar:/home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar:/home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar:/home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar:/home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/javax.inject-1.jar:/home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/jersey-core-1.9.jar:/home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/jersey-guice-1.9.jar:/home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/jersey-server-1.9.jar:/home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/junit-4.11.jar:/home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/leveldbjni-all-1.8.jar:/home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar:/home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/netty-3.6.2.Final.jar:/home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/paranamer-2.3.jar:/home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar:/home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/snappy-java-1.0.4.1.jar:/home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/xz-1.0.jar:/home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-app-2.7.1.jar:/home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-common-2.7.1.jar:/home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-2.7.1.jar:/home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-hs-2.7.1.jar:/home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-hs-plugins-2.7.1.jar:/home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient-2.7.1.jar:/home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient-2.7.1-tests.jar:/home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-shuffle-2.7.1.jar:/home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.7.1.jar:/home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib:/home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib-examples:/home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/sources:/home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/contrib/capacity-scheduler/*.jar:/lib/*' -Djava.library.path=:/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib org.apache.flume.node.Application -conf ./conf/ -f conf/flume.conf -n TwitterAgent
bin/flume-ng: line 241: /usr/lib/java/jdk1.8.0_131: Is a directory
bin/flume-ng: line 241: exec: /usr/lib/java/jdk1.8.0_131: cannot execute: Is a directory
```

Comment: What did you put in `JAVA_HOME` in flume-env.sh? The error seems to be in `+ exec /usr/lib/java/jdk1.8.0_131 bin/java` which should have been `+ exec /usr/lib/java/jdk1.8.0_131/bin/java`

Comment: In flume-env.sh I have put this - JAVA_HOME = /usr/lib/java/jdk1.8.0_131

Comment: Can you share what you put?

Comment: JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/java/jdk1.8.0_131"

Comment: There should be export too, isn't it? And can you apply java commands in your terminal? What does `java -version` shows?

Comment: hadoop1@ubuntu:~$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_131"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_131-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.131-b11, mixed mode)
hadoop1@ubuntu:~$

Comment: One last task. Can you search for java related lines in `.bashrc` file and share them too?

Comment: no need of export, we can directly start with JAVA_HOME in flume-env.sh

Comment: export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/java/jdk1.8.0_131
export PATH="$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin"

Comment: Everything seems to be in place. Can you run the command with --conf this time if you haven't done so?

Comment: Final task I would like you to do is `echo $PATH` and share me the result. I have replicated the error you are getting in yours. And I want to be sure if thats the reason. So please share me the result of `echo $PATH`.

Comment: hadoop1@ubuntu:~$ echo $PATH
/home/hadoop1/Downloads/apache-flume-1.6.0-bin/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/lib/java/jdk1.8.0_131/bin:/home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/bin:/home/hadoop1/Desktop/hadoop/sbin
hadoop1@ubuntu:~$

Comment: I have tried to run the command with --conf, but I get the same error...

Comment: Do you remember how many places have you set JAVA_HOME?

Comment: I have set JAVA_HOME in .bashrc, hadoop-env.sh and flume-env.sh  But, the error is with respect to 241 line in flume-ng.                      $EXEC $JAVA_HOME "bin/java" $JAVA_OPTS $FLUME_JAVA_OPTS "${arr_java_props[@]}" -cp "$FLUME_CLASSPATH" \
      -Djava.library.path=$FLUME_JAVA_LIBRARY_PATH

Comment: Yes thats the culprit line. You got it. I guess your flume is a currupted one. I have `  $EXEC $JAVA_HOME/bin/java $JAVA_OPTS $FLUME_JAVA_OPTS "${arr_java_props[@]}" -cp "$FLUME_CLASSPATH" \
      -Djava.library.path=$FLUME_JAVA_LIBRARY_PATH "$FLUME_APPLICATION_CLASS" $*` and its not in 241 line but 214 line. So either you change that line or install latest version of flume.

Comment: Which version of flume have you installed? I have installed apache-flume-1.6.0-bin

Comment: Its 1.7.0 the latest one. https://flume.apache.org/download.html

Comment: Can't get the data into browsing HDFS local host:50070/explore.html#/user/flume/tweets

Comment: What do you mean by can't get the data into browsing? Is your flume working now?

Comment: Flume is working but the data which is processed, needs to be stored in a directory and must appear in browsing history of local host: 50070....which is not happening

Comment: You should be asking another question for that.  Please answer this question with details of what you did. And accept your answer so that others can benefit from it

Comment: Well, I had earlier installed the older version of flume apache-flume-1.6.0-bin which gave an error in 241 line of flume-ng with the java path. So, I had to install the latest version of flume ie. apache-flume-1.7.0-bin and I tried to run the command to start the flume-agent. It was working then....thanks for the help Ramesh Maharjan

Comment: I wanted you to post an answer below and accept it as well. :)

Comment: May be you are not authorized to answer your question, is that so? Shall I answer it?

Comment: Ya...you answer it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `java path` that `flume-ng agent` is using is malformed. 
The error seems to be in `+ exec /usr/lib/java/jdk1.8.0_131 bin/java` which should have been `+ exec /usr/lib/java/jdk1.8.0_131/bin/java` without the space in between

It should either be one of the followings

1 you are setting `JAVA_HOME` wrong somewhere (.bashrc or flume-env.sh or ...)

2 the `flume-ng` is malformed and using malformed java path.

So you will have to correct any two of these. From my communication with you it seems that your java path seems good.

So you will have to download the latest `Flume` and see if the issue resolves.
Thanks